# I can access associativeArray[a][2][1] correctly.(0<= a< 2) But if want to access associativeArray[a][2][0], it gives me wrong result

Tags: php

0621 - is STD code
22465874 - is phone number.

I can access  phone number correctly but using $associativeArray[0][2][0] gives wrong value.

```
     <?php
error_reporting(0);


echo "<br>";

$associativeArray = array(

                        array(1, "Rahul", array(0621, 22465874)),
                        array(2, "Ayushi", array(0261, 2265471)),
                        array(3, "Ritik", array(2314, 4789556))


                    );


echo $associativeArray[0][2][0], "<br>";
echo $associativeArray[0][2][1];
?>
```

Comment: In fact, you can access `$associativeArray[a][2][0]`, only the value it stores is not what you expect. Your expectations are incorrect, `0621` is the octal representation of `401` (`=6*8^2+2*8+1`).

Comment: A phone number is not a number. It is a sequence of digits that can start with `0` and can also contain non-digit characters (`+`, `#` etc). A phone number is a string, despite being called a "number". It used to be a number back in the days when the phone was invented, before special phone numbers, area codes and international prefixes were invented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a number start with a zero, it is interpreted as an octal number by [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

So you simply have to put your phone numbers in quotes to avoid problems:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

echo "<br>";

$associativeArray = array(
    array(1, "Rahul", array('0621', '22465874')),
    array(2, "Ayushi", array('0261', '2265471')),
    array(3, "Ritik", array('2314', '4789556'))
);

echo $associativeArray[0][2][0], "<br>";
echo $associativeArray[0][2][1];
?>
```

Output:

> ```
> <br>0621<br>22465874
> ```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/c48jl